# Word for developing and refining a product: Choppa - dowa?

Tags: word-requests

and thank you for making time to help me with this question.

I met with a supplier recently, and they told me that in China there was a word for the process of developing and refining a product.

The concept as explained to me was pronounced choppa-dowa.

What is the correct spelling/pronunciation/interpretation of that concept?

Thank you so much again - Norman Lutes

Comment: I'm a native Chinese speaker but really have no idea.

Comment: It's very unlikely that anybody will be able to reconstruct that term based on what you think you have heard and how you spell it and how that spelling is pronounced by other people. Your best chance is to ask your business partner next time you see them.

Answer (score 1):

Closest I can think of is 产品开发, or chanpin-kaifa (product development).

Where in China did you hear this? Sounds southern.

Comment: It may be some kind of jargon invented by a marketer or a business school, but it definitely exists on line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the word was 研發 yánfā/yanfa, an abbreviated Chinese calque translation of "research and development" (equivalent to R&D)

Answer (score 0):

If you met and spoke in person to a supplier, you should have asked them to write down the Chinese characters and pinyin if you are genuinely interested to take note of specific terms.

Now given "choppa-dowa" is nowhere near any Chinese pronunciation, if I was to hazard a guess that might come close, I would try 產品優化 chan-pin you-hua (pronounced Ch-ah'n Peen Y'Oh Hwah) meaning Product Refinery (to make improvements to an existing product).